# Webmin not showing running processes after upgrade to Ubuntu Server 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, webmin

A little background- I recently upgraded my headless Ubuntu Server 18.04 install to 20.04. In that process, webmin somehow was gone from my system. The repository was disabled. So I re-enabled, then re-installed. Most everything was where I wanted it to be (SMB server config) and basically only my menu customizations and custom commands were gone.

Now, on webmin, it will not show running processes. It say's 0. That is the only thing I've noticed that is broken. So I posted on webmin's [github](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/1237) page, and got a prompt response that the issue was fixed [here](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/commit/613f3a5f41fd094037629965e4cea1b815ac2b7d). So I guess my question is more of a git question than a webmin question, because I really am not sure how to implement the fix on that page to my webmin install. If anyone can steer me in the right direction I'd be appreciative of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That helped me out!  I couldn't figure out how to download that as a patch, but the file it is referencing on my system was under /usr/share/webmin/proc/.  There I backed up linux.lib.pl then edited it in nano.  There I changed the lines noted in the patch (+ for add, - for take away), saved, and it worked.  Otherwise if I could download it I would have just used the patch command.

Comment: thank you. it's fixed on my end now. I couldn't figure it out. for some reason using github is alien to me.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the other.. i do the following:

as root user:

```
# cd /usr/share/webmin/proc
# mv linux-lib.pl linux-lib.bkp.pl
# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webmin/webmin/613f3a5f41fd094037629965e4cea1b815ac2b7d/proc/linux-lib.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# linux-lib.pl
# Functions for parsing linux ps output

use Time::Local;

sub get_ps_version
{
if (!$get_ps_version_cache) {
        local $out = &backquote_command("ps V 2>&1");
        if ($out =~ /version\s+([0-9\.]+)\./ ||
            $out =~ /\S+\s+([3-9][0-9\.]+)\./) {
                $get_ps_version_cache = $1;
                }
        }
return $get_ps_version_cache;
}

sub list_processes
{
local($pcmd, $line, $i, %pidmap, @plist, $dummy, @w, $_);
local $ver = &get_ps_version();
if ($ver && $ver < 2) {
        # Old version of ps
        $pcmd = join(' ' , @_);
        open(PS, "ps aulxhwwww $pcmd 2>/dev/nul |");
        for($i=0; $line=<PS>; $i++) {
                chop($line);
                if ($line =~ /ps aulxhwwww/) { $i--; next; }
                if ($line !~ /^\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\-\d]+)\s+([\-\d]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S*)\s+(\S+)[\s<>N]+(\S+)\s+([0-9:]+)\s+(.*)$/) {
                        $i--;
                        next;
                        }
                $pidmap{$3} = $i;
                $plist[$i]->{"pid"} = $3;
                $plist[$i]->{"ppid"} = $4;
                $plist[$i]->{"user"} = getpwuid($2);
                $plist[$i]->{"size"} = "$7 kB";
                $plist[$i]->{"cpu"} = "Unknown";
                $plist[$i]->{"time"} = $12;
                $plist[$i]->{"nice"} = $6;
                $plist[$i]->{"args"} = $13;
                $plist[$i]->{"_pri"} = $5;
                $plist[$i]->{"_tty"} = $11 eq "?" ? $text{'edit_none'} : "/dev/tty$11";
                $plist[$i]->{"_status"} = $stat_map{substr($10, 0, 1)};
                ($plist[$i]->{"_wchan"} = $9) =~ s/\s+$//g;
                if (!$plist[$i]->{"_wchan"}) { delete($plist[$i]->{"_wchan"}); }
                if ($plist[$i]->{"args"} =~ /^\((.*)\)/)
                        { $plist[$i]->{"args"} = $1; }
                }
        close(PS);
        open(PS, "ps auxh $pcmd |");
        while($line=<PS>) {
                if ($line =~ /^\s*(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+/ &&
                    defined($pidmap{$2})) {
                        $plist[$pidmap{$2}]->{"cpu"} = $3;
                        $plist[$pidmap{$2}]->{"_mem"} = "$4 %";
                        }
                }
        close(PS);
}
else {
        # New version of ps, as found in redhat 6
        local $width;
        if ($ver >= 3.2) {
                # Use width format character if allowed
                $width = ":80";
                }
        open(PS, "ps --cols 2048 -eo user$width,ruser$width,group$width,rgroup$width,pid,ppid,pgid,pcpu,vsz,nice,etime,time,stime,tty,args 2>/dev/null |");
        $dummy = <PS>;
        my @now = localtime(time());
        for($i=0; $line=<PS>; $i++) {
                chop($line);
                $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
                eval { @w = split(/\s+/, $line, -1); };
                if ($@) {
                        # Hit a split loop
                        $i--; next;
                        }
                if ($line =~ /ps --cols 500 -eo user/) {
                        # Skip process ID 0 or ps command
                        $i--; next;
                        }
                if (@_ && &indexof($w[4], @_) < 0) {
                        # Not interested in this PID
                        $i--; next;
                        }
                $plist[$i]->{"pid"} = $w[4];
                $plist[$i]->{"ppid"} = $w[5];
                $plist[$i]->{"user"} = $w[0];
                $plist[$i]->{"cpu"} = "$w[7] %";
                $plist[$i]->{"size"} = "$w[8] kB";
                $plist[$i]->{"bytes"} = $w[8]*1024;
                $plist[$i]->{"time"} = $w[11];
                $plist[$i]->{"_stime"} = $w[12];
                eval {
                        if (($w[12] =~ /^(\d+):(\d+)$/ ||
                             $w[12] =~ /^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/) &&
                            $3 < 60 && $2 < 60 && $1 < 24) {
                                # Started today
                                $plist[$i]->{"_stime_unix"} =
                                        timelocal($3 || 0, $2, $1,
                                                  $now[3], $now[4], $now[5]);
                                }
                        elsif ($w[12] =~ /^(\S\S\S)\s*(\d+)$/ && $2 < 32) {
                                # Started on some other day
                                $plist[$i]->{"_stime_unix"} =
                                        timelocal(0, 0, 0, $2,
                                                &month_to_number($1), $now[5]);
                                }
                        };
                $plist[$i]->{"nice"} = $w[9];
                $plist[$i]->{"args"} = @w<15 ? "defunct" : join(' ', @w[14..$#w]);
                $plist[$i]->{"_group"} = $w[2];
                $plist[$i]->{"_ruser"} = $w[1];
                $plist[$i]->{"_rgroup"} = $w[3];
                $plist[$i]->{"_pgid"} = $w[6];
                $plist[$i]->{"_tty"} = $w[13] =~ /\?/ ? $text{'edit_none'} : "/dev/$w[13]";
                }
        close(PS);
        }
return @plist;
}

# renice_proc(pid, nice)
sub renice_proc
{
return undef if (&is_readonly_mode());
local $out = &backquote_logged("renice $_[1] -p $_[0] 2>&1");
if ($?) { return $out; }
return undef;
}

# find_mount_processes(mountpoint)
# Find all processes under some mount point
sub find_mount_processes
{
local($out);
&has_command("fuser") || &error("fuser command is not installed");
$out = &backquote_command("fuser -m ".quotemeta($_[0])." 2>/dev/null");
$out =~ s/[^0-9 ]//g;
$out =~ s/^\s+//g; $out =~ s/\s+$//g;
return split(/\s+/, $out);
}

# find_file_processes([file]+)
# Find all processes with some file open
sub find_file_processes
{
local($out, $files);
&has_command("fuser") || &error("fuser command is not installed");
$files = join(' ', map { quotemeta($_) } map { glob($_) } @_);
$out = &backquote_command("fuser $files 2>/dev/null");
$out =~ s/[^0-9 ]//g;
$out =~ s/^\s+//g; $out =~ s/\s+$//g;
return split(/\s+/, $out);
}

# get_new_pty()
# Returns the filehandles and names for a pty and tty
sub get_new_pty
{
if (-r "/dev/ptmx" && -d "/dev/pts" && open(PTMX, "+>/dev/ptmx")) {
        # Can use new-style PTY number allocation device
        local $unl;
        local $ptn;

        # ioctl to unlock the PTY (TIOCSPTLCK)
        $unl = pack("i", 0);
        ioctl(PTMX, 0x40045431, $unl) || &error("Unlock ioctl failed : $!");
        $unl = unpack("i", $unl);

        # ioctl to request a TTY (TIOCGPTN)
        ioctl(PTMX, 0x80045430, $ptn) || &error("PTY ioctl failed : $!");
        $ptn = unpack("i", $ptn);

        local $tty = "/dev/pts/$ptn";
        return (*PTMX, undef, $tty, $tty);
        }
else {
        # Have to search manually through pty files!
        local @ptys;
        local $devstyle;
        if (-d "/dev/pty") {
                opendir(DEV, "/dev/pty");
                @ptys = map { "/dev/pty/$_" } readdir(DEV);
                closedir(DEV);
                $devstyle = 1;
                }
        else {
                opendir(DEV, "/dev");
                @ptys = map { "/dev/$_" } (grep { /^pty/ } readdir(DEV));
                closedir(DEV);
                $devstyle = 0;
                }
        local ($pty, $tty);
        foreach $pty (@ptys) {
                open(PTY, "+>$pty") || next;
                local $tty = $pty;
                if ($devstyle == 0) {
                        $tty =~ s/pty/tty/;
                        }
                else {
                        $tty =~ s/m(\d+)$/s$1/;
                        }
                local $old = select(PTY); $| = 1; select($old);
                if ($< == 0) {
                        # Don't need to open the TTY file here for root,
                        # as it will be opened later after the controlling
                        # TTY has been released.
                        return (*PTY, undef, $pty, $tty);
                        }
                else {
                        # Must open now ..
                        open(TTY, "+>$tty");
                        select(TTY); $| = 1; select($old);
                        return (*PTY, *TTY, $pty, $tty);
                        }
                }
        return ();
        }
}

# close_controlling_pty()
# Disconnects this process from it's controlling PTY, if connected
sub close_controlling_pty
{
if (open(DEVTTY, "/dev/tty")) {
        # Special ioctl to disconnect (TIOCNOTTY)
        ioctl(DEVTTY, 0x5422, 0);
        close(DEVTTY);
        }
}

# open_controlling_pty(ptyfh, ttyfh, ptyfile, ttyfile)
# Makes a PTY returned from get_new_pty the controlling TTY (/dev/tty) for
# this process.
sub open_controlling_pty
{
local ($ptyfh, $ttyfh, $pty, $tty) = @_;

# Call special ioctl to attach /dev/tty to this new tty (TIOCSCTTY)
ioctl($ttyfh, 0x540e, 0);
}

# get_memory_info()
# Returns a list containing the real mem, free real mem, swap and free swap,
# and possibly cached memory and the burstable limit. All of these are in Kb.
sub get_memory_info
{
local %m;
local $memburst;
if (&running_in_openvz() && open(BEAN, "/proc/user_beancounters")) {
        # If we are running under Virtuozzo, there may be a limit on memory
        # use in force that is less than the real system's memory. Or it may be
        # a higher 'burstable' limit. Use this, unless it is unreasonably
        # high (like 1TB)
        local $pagesize = 1024;
        eval {
                use POSIX;
                $pagesize = POSIX::sysconf(POSIX::_SC_PAGESIZE);
                };
        while(<BEAN>) {
                if (/privvmpages\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/ &&
                    $3 < 1024*1024*1024*1024) {
                        $memburst = $3 * $pagesize / 1024;
                        last;
                        }
                }
        close(BEAN);
        }
open(MEMINFO, "/proc/meminfo") || return ();
while(<MEMINFO>) {
        if (/^(\S+):\s+(\d+)/) {
                $m{lc($1)} = $2;
                }
        }
close(MEMINFO);
local $memtotal;
if ($memburst && $memburst > $m{'memtotal'}) {
        # Burstable limit is higher than actual RAM
        $memtotal = $m{'memtotal'};
        }
elsif ($memburst && $memburst < $m{'memtotal'}) {
        # Limit is less than actual RAM
        $memtotal = $memburst;
        $memburst = undef;
        }
elsif ($memburst && $memburst == $m{'memtotal'}) {
        # Same as actual RAM
        $memtotal = $memburst;
        $memburst = undef;
        }
elsif (!$memburst) {
        # No burstable limit set, like on a real system
        $memtotal = $m{'memtotal'};
        }
return ( $memtotal,
         $m{'cached'} > $memtotal ? $m{'memfree'} :
                $m{'memfree'}+$m{'buffers'}+$m{'cached'},
         $m{'swaptotal'}, $m{'swapfree'},
         $m{'buffers'} + $m{'cached'},
         $memburst, );
}

# os_get_cpu_info()
# Returns a list containing the 5, 10 and 15 minute load averages, and the
# CPU mhz, model, vendor, cache and count
sub os_get_cpu_info
{
open(LOAD, "/proc/loadavg") || return ();
local @load = split(/\s+/, <LOAD>);
close(LOAD);
local %c;
open(CPUINFO, "/proc/cpuinfo");
while(<CPUINFO>) {
        if (/^(\S[^:]*\S)\s*:\s*(.*)/) {
                $c{lc($1)} = $2;
                }
        }
close(CPUINFO);
$c{'model name'} =~ s/\d+\s*mhz//i;
if ($c{'cache size'} =~ /^(\d+)\s+KB/i) {
        $c{'cache size'} = $1*1024;
        }
elsif ($c{'cache size'} =~ /^(\d+)\s+MB/i) {
        $c{'cache size'} = $1*1024*1024;
        }
if (!$c{'cpu mhz'} && $c{'model name'}) {
        $c{'bogomips'} =~ s/\..*$//;
        $c{'model name'} .= " @ ".$c{'bogomips'}." bMips";
        }

# Merge in info from /proc/device-tree
if (!$c{'model name'}) {
        $c{'model name'} = &read_file_contents("/proc/device-tree/model");
        }

if ($c{'model name'}) {
        return ( $load[0], $load[1], $load[2],
                 int($c{'cpu mhz'}), $c{'model name'}, $c{'vendor_id'},
                 $c{'cache size'}, $c{'processor'}+1 );
        }
else {
        return ( $load[0], $load[1], $load[2] );
        }
}

$has_trace_command = &has_command("strace");

# open_process_trace(pid, [&syscalls])
# Starts tracing on some process, and returns a trace object
sub open_process_trace
{
local $fh = time().$$;
local $sc;
if (@{$_[1]}) {
        $sc = "-e trace=".join(",", @{$_[1]});
        }
local $tpid = open($fh, "strace -t -p $_[0] $sc 2>&1 |");
$line = <$fh>;
return { 'pid' => $_[0],
         'tpid' => $tpid,
         'fh' => $fh };
}

# close_process_trace(&trace)
# Halts tracing on some trace object
sub close_process_trace
{
kill('TERM', $_[0]->{'tpid'}) if ($_[0]->{'tpid'});
close($_[0]->{'fh'});
}

# read_process_trace(&trace)
# Returns an action structure representing one action by traced process, or
# undef if an error occurred
sub read_process_trace
{
local $fh = $_[0]->{'fh'};
local @tm = localtime(time());
while(1) {
        local $line = <$fh>;
        return undef if (!$line);
        if ($line =~ /^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+([^\(]+)\((.*)\)\s*=\s*(\-?\d+|\?)/) {
                local $tm = timelocal($3, $2, $1, $tm[3], $tm[4], $tm[5]);
                local $action = { 'time' => $tm,
                                  'call' => $4,
                                  'rv' => $6 eq "?" ? undef : $6 };
                local $args = $5;
                local @args;
                while(1) {
                        if ($args =~ /^[ ,]*(\{[^}]*\})(.*)$/) {
                                # A structure in { }
                                push(@args, $1);
                                $args = $2;
                                }
                        elsif ($args =~ /^[ ,]*"([^"]*)"\.*(.*)$/) {
                                # A quoted string
                                push(@args, $1);
                                $args = $2;
                                }
                        elsif ($args =~ /^[ ,]*\[([^\]]*)\](.*)$/) {
                                # A square-bracket number
                                push(@args, $1);
                                $args = $2;
                                }
                        elsif ($args =~ /^[ ,]*\<([^\>]*)\>(.*)$/) {
                                # An angle-bracketed string
                                push(@args, $1);
                                $args = $2;
                                }
                        elsif ($args =~ /[ ,]*([^, ]+)(.*)$/) {
                                # Just a number
                                push(@args, $1);
                                $args = $2;
                                }
                        else {
                                last;
                                }
                        }
                if ($args[$#args] eq $action->{'rv'}) {
                        pop(@args);     # last arg is same as return value?
                        }
                $action->{'args'} = \@args;
                return $action;
                }
        }
}

foreach $ia (keys %text) {
        if ($ia =~ /^linux(_\S+)/) {
                $info_arg_map{$1} = $text{$ia};
                }
        elsif ($ia =~ /^linuxstat_(\S+)/) {
                $stat_map{$1} = $text{$ia};
                }
        }

@nice_range = (-20 .. 20);

$has_fuser_command = 1;

# os_list_scheduling_classes()
# Returns a list of Linux scheduling classes, if supported. Each element is a
# 2-element array ref containing a code and description.
sub os_list_scheduling_classes
{
if (&has_command("ionice")) {
        return ( [ 1, $text{'linux_real'} ],
                 [ 2, $text{'linux_be'} ],
                 [ 3, $text{'linux_idle'} ] );
        }
return ( );
}

# os_list_scheduling_priorities()
# Returns a list of IO priorities, each of which is an array ref containing
# a number and description
sub os_list_scheduling_priorities
{
return ( [ 0, "0 ($text{'edit_prihigh'})" ],
         [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ],
         [ 7, "7 ($text{'edit_prilow'})" ] );
}

# os_get_scheduling_class(pid)
# Returns the IO scheduling class and priority for a running program
sub os_get_scheduling_class
{
local ($pid) = @_;
local $out = &backquote_command("ionice -p ".quotemeta($pid));
if ($out =~ /^(realtime|best-effort|idle|none):\s+prio\s+(\d+)/) {
        return ($1 eq "realtime" ? 1 : $1 eq "best-effort" ? 2 :
                $1 eq "idle" ? 3 : 0, $2);
        }
return ( );
}

# os_set_scheduling_class(pid, class, priority)
# Sets the ID scheduling class and priority for some process. Returns an error
# message on failure, undef on success.
sub os_set_scheduling_class
{
local ($pid, $class, $prio) = @_;
local $cmd = "ionice -c ".quotemeta($class);
$cmd .= " -n ".quotemeta($prio) if (defined($prio));
$cmd .= " -p ".quotemeta($pid);
local $out = &backquote_logged("$cmd 2>&1 </dev/null");
return $? ? $out : undef;
}

# get_current_cpu_temps()
# Returns a list of hash refs containing CPU temperatures
sub get_current_cpu_temps
{
my @rv;
if (&has_command("sensors")) {
        my $fh = "SENSORS";
        &open_execute_command($fh, "sensors </dev/null 2>/dev/null", 1);
        while(<$fh>) {
                if (/Core\s+(\d+):\s+([\+\-][0-9\.]+)/) {
                        push(@rv, { 'core' => $1,
                                    'temp' => $2 });
                        }
                elsif (/CPU:\s+([\+\-][0-9\.]+)/) {
                        push(@rv, { 'core' => 0,
                                    'temp' => $1 });
                        }
                }
        close($fh);
        }
return @rv;
}

# get_cpu_io_usage()
# Returns a list containing CPU user, kernel, idle, io and VM time, and IO
# blocks in and out
sub get_cpu_io_usage
{
my $out,@lines,@w;
if (&has_command("vmstat")) {
        $out = &backquote_command("vmstat 1 2 2>/dev/null");
        @lines = split(/\r?\n/, $out);
        @w = split(/\s+/, $lines[$#lines]);
        shift(@w) if ($w[0] eq '');
        if ($w[8] =~ /^\d+$/ && $w[9] =~ /^\d+$/) {
            return ( @w[12..16], $w[8], $w[9] );
        }
    } elsif (&has_command("dstat")) {
        $out = &backquote_command("dstat 1 1 2>/dev/null");
        @lines = split(/\r?\n/, $out);
        @w = split(/[\s|]+/, $lines[$#lines]);
        shift(@w) if ($w[0] eq '');
        return( @w[0..4], @w[6..7]);
    }
    return undef;
}

1;

`
```

Comment: Copy paste the above in it's entirety to /usr/share/webmin/proc/linix-lib.pl